# Vue.js - Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am getting error "Property or method "processForm" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render" and error "TypeError: _vm.processForm is not a function". I am calling the processForm function in my contact form via `@submit.prevent="processForm"`. I'm not sure what to do from this point. Any help appreciated.

render.js:

```
const mjml2html = require('mjml')
const Vue = require('vue')

const app = new Vue({
data: {
    el: '#signupform',
    name: ''
},
template: `
<mj-section>
 <mj-column>
   <mj-text font-size="20px" color="#F45E43" font-family="helvetica">Hello {{ name }}</mj-text>
 </mj-column>
</mj-section>`,
methods: {
processForm: function() {
    renderer.renderToString(app).then(html => {
        const htmlWithoutDataServerRenderedAttribute = html.replace(`data-server-rendered="true"`,'')
        const plainHtml = mjml2html(htmlWithoutDataServerRenderedAttribute)
        console.log(plainHtml.html)
    })}}})

const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer({
template: `
<mjml>
 <mj-body>
  <!--vue-ssr-outlet-->
 </mj-body>
</mjml>`
})
```

And my form template:

```
<template>
   <div class="sign_up" id="signupform">
     <main role="main">
      <div class="SignUp_container">
      <form class="form-signup" @submit.prevent="processForm">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter First Name" required/>
      <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required/>
      <input type="email" name="mailaddr" placeholder="Your email address" required/>
      <div class="sign_cancel_buttons">
      <router-link to="/">
        <button id="canlbtn" type="cancel" class="clbtn">
          Cancel
        </button>
         </router-link> 
        <button id="signupbtn" type="submit" name="sendmsg-button" class="signbtn">
          Sign Up
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Your root component defined a `processForm` method which applies only to its template, yet you're trying to call it somewhere else

Comment: If I move the `processForm` method and  `const renderer` code to the form template I get an error "Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils.js'"

Comment: Nevertheless, `processForm` must go with the template you call it from.  Since the `renderer` definition is not part of any component, try placing it at the top with the other `require` statements.  Even if you still get the error, at least everything will be in its right place.  I can't comment on the rest because I never try to use `vue-server-renderer`.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the form data from template to the render.js file and have the render.js file return the `plainHtml` data to my template? Esentially, i want to take the name input from the template, give it to the render file so it can replace {{name}} with the user input and then convert the mjml code to html so that i can send it out via email.

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be with Vuex.  You would save the form data in the store, and then access the store data from `render.js`.  You could also `$emit` the form data to the root component.